# Combining api request

Tags: json, angular, httprequest, observable

I am new to Angular2 and just started to work with Http request and observables.
Previously I worked with .NET and MySql, and I am now trying to learn the best practice working with data from API’s.

I am used to join tables, and I would like to find the best way to combine json data.
In this example I want the user to fill a form and type his phone number.

The prefix of the phone number is a dropdownlist with country code and prefix f.ex.  Germany +49
Therefor I need an object: { “Germany”:”49”,  Cambodia:"855" ….}

I make 2 http request to country.io:

```
  http://country.io/phone.json  // e.g. DE: “Germany”
  http://country.io/names.json // e.g. DE: “49”
```

From these 2 request I used the code below to make my new json object : myPhonePrefixObject

I think the code is too long, and that it must be possible to do it in a better way.

*country-service.ts:*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

    constructor(  private _http:Http) { }

    getCountryCode(): Observable<any> {      
       return this._http.get('http://crossorigin.me/http://country.io/phone.json')
            .map(countryCodes => countryCodes.json());
    }

    getPhonePrefix(): Observable<any> {      
       return this._http.get('http://crossorigin.me/http://country.io/names.json')
            .map(phonePrefix => phonePrefix.json());
    }    

}
```

*Code inside userform.component in where I import the CountryService*

```
myPhonePrefixObject; 

this.countryPhonePrefix()
    .then((pp) => {
        myPhonePrefixObject = pp;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


 private getCountryCode() {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this._countryService.getCountryCode()
        .subscribe(
            res => resolve(res)
        ); 
 });      
}


private getPhonePrefix() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this._countryService.getPhonePrefix()
        .subscribe(
            res => resolve(res),
            error => reject(error)
        );
 });                 
}


private countryPhonePrefix() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let cc: Object;
    this.getCountryCode()
        .then((cCode) => {
            cc = cCode;
            return this.getPhonePrefix()
        })
        .then((pPrefix) => {
            let pp: Object = {};
            Object.keys(cc).forEach((key, index) => {
                pp[cc[key]] = pPrefix[key];
            });               
            resolve(pp);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        }); 
 });      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET developer here too!

To deal with multiple streams, you will need aggregation methods. In this case, you want to yield the object based on the result of 2 streams (HTTP requests), the aggregation method you are looking for is `combineLatest`. It combines the 2 streams and let you define the output data based on 2 sources:

```
getCombinedData(): Observable<Data> {
  return this.getCountryPhones().combineLatest(this.getCountryNames(),
    (phoneData, nameData) => {
      var resultData = {};
      Object.keys(nameData).forEach((key) => {
        resultData[nameData[key]] = phoneData[key];
      });

      return resultData;
    });
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/agUPNujG3NnbKI6J3ZVJ?p=preview

Comment: Hi Harry
Thank you so much!!
That was exactly what I was searching for and his answer helped me a lot!